# Create new calligraphic style

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I want to create a new calligraphic style in latex.

Namely, I want to create a macro `\bmathcal` so that `\bmathcal{P}` gives rise to `\boldsymbol{\mathcal{P}}`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\def\bmathcal#1{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{#1}}}}
```

Comment: No need for `\ensuremath`.

Comment: @Manuel, you are right. `\ensuremath` just allows to call `\bmathcal` from any context (and not only in math mode).